# Why can't I update pip on Windows 7?

Tags: python, django, pip

I downloaded pip from [the pip website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip) and ran it on Python IDLE
 3.4. When I did that, it says

> You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 9.0.1 is available.

So I tried to upgrade it on command prompt using

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

but then this came up:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions
>   : )
>   No matching distribution found for install

Why doesn't it let me update pip?

Answer (score 0):

One will most likely need to do `pip install pip --upgrade` from an admin `cmd` window. Right click `cmd.exe` and click `Run as Administrator`.